# Regular Expression working in .Net but not in Classic ASP

Tags: .net, regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have the below regular expression which is working fine in .NET however it is not working in Classic ASP. The Regular expression is used to validate for a least one digit and one character.

The expression is:

```
Set regPassword = New RegExp
regPassword.Pattern = "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{6,30}$"
Response.Write(regPassword.Test("Test456"))
```

The result of the above returns False.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: .. and there is length control either, could be related this? I think you should update your query with the tested codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^.(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]){6,30}
```

[Here is a good resource on the VBScript Regex engine.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

Edit: According to the comments, this works?

```
(.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: Seems like the expression is behaving different from the .NET. Because now it has to start with a digit to be valid.

Comment: Interesting. The code works on my (returns true). How do you handle the condition results? I wonder do you think the -1 is False? Also, try this one `If regPassword.Test("Test456") Then Response.Write "pattern works"`

Comment: I tried this `(.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z])` and it works, however when i do `^(.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]){6,30}$` it doesn't. I tried also my original version and didn't work.

PS i tried `If regPassword.Test("Test456") Then Response.Write "pattern works"` with the same outcome.

Comment: So, the second one works... it's possible that your version of ASP doesn't support lookaheads in regular expressions, even though VBScript does. I updated the answer with the one that worked.

Comment: I will use two regular expressions. Thanks for your help